# Display date in ng-repeat input field - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to display the date in ng-repeat from an array inside the input field. I am able to display but the first index value gets reflected in all the fields.

```
$scope.trackPaymentDetails = [{"itemNo": 1, "nextduedate": "Jan 02, 2010", "Status": "Paid", "amount": 1000}, {"itemNo": 2, "Status": "Unpaid", "amount": 5000}];

<table class="table table-hover" novalidate>

<tr>
<th>&nbsp;&nbsp;S.No.</th>
<th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Amount</th>
<th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Due Date</th>
</tr>

<tbody>
<tr dir-paginate="item in trackPaymentDetails |orderBy:sortkey:reverse|itemsPerPage:2">
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$index + 1}}</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.amount}}</td>
<td><input class="form-control7" type="text" id="trackPaymentDueDate_{{$index}}"  name="duedate" ng-model="model.nextduedate" required readonly="readonly" datepicker-popup="MMM dd, yyyy" placeholder=" " style="background-color: transparent;" value={{item.nextduedate}}></td>
</tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: That's probably because your are using the same `ng-model` and `value` for all of them. Possibly neglected code: `ng-model="model.nextduedate"  value={{item.nextduedate}}>`

Comment: I am using date picker js file as shown in this sample plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/HXbevW?p=preview. So my ng-repeat is not working in this. Can you help me? How to display date and change the date.

Answer (score 0):

you are not using `ng-repeat`. you are using `dir-paginate`. change it first. then in the input add the `item.nextduedate` as the `ng-model` value.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.model = {};

$scope.trackPaymentDetails = [{"itemNo": 1, "nextduedate": "Jan 02, 2010", "Status": "Paid", "amount": 1000}, {"itemNo": 2, "Status": "Unpaid", "amount": 5000}];

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <table class="table table-hover" novalidate>

<tr>
<th>&nbsp;&nbsp;S.No.</th>
<th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Amount</th>
<th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Due Date</th>
</tr>

<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in trackPaymentDetails">
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$index + 1}}</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.amount}}</td>
<td><input class="form-control7" type="text" id="trackPaymentDueDate_{{$index}}"  name="duedate" ng-model="item.nextduedate" required readonly="readonly" datepicker-popup="MMM dd, yyyy" placeholder=" " style="background-color: transparent;" ></td>
</tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using the date picker js file as shown in this sample plunker plnkr.co/edit/HXbevW?p=preview. So my ng-repeat is not working in this. Can you help me? How to display date and change the date.